# Calling a method, but don't know from which class

Tags: java, class

Bear with me on this one... I'm having a little trouble finding the words to explain what I want to do.

I have 26 classes. Each of which have methods with the same name, return type and parameters. The class names are aWord(), bWord(), cWord etc.

The methods accept a single char as a parameter and return a String[].

The following code works, but is super lengthy, and I would have to do it every time I want a different method:

```
if (firstChar == 'a'){aWord word = new aWord(); wordArray = word.returnWordArray();}
else if (firstChar == 'b'){bWord word = new bWord(); wordArray = word.returnWordArray();}
    else if (firstChar == 'c'){cWord word = new cWord(); wordArray = word.returnWordArray();}
    else if (firstChar == 'd'){dWord word = new dWord(); wordArray = word.returnWordArray();}
```

Ideally, I'd be able to have something like:

```
String className = char + "Word";
className thisClass = new className();

String[] stringy = className.returnWordArray();
```

Any idea what a) I'm talking about and b) how I would go about doing it?

Comment: One thought is that instead of having to create 26 objects, you could always make the methods `static`. Then you would just have to call them using the class name.

Comment: Why 26 classes? Wouldnt 26 instances of ONE class good enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is reflection and why is it useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Comment: Sounds like you want to do a bit of metaprogramming to me. You won't be altogether that lucky with java though. You could of course abbreviate all of this a bit by simply creating the instance within a `switch`-clause and afterwards calling `returnWordArray`. If they don't inherit the same class, your best shot would be reflection. I'd definitely start searching for a completely different approach than what you use.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at Factory Create software pattern  which is basically what you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this with reflection.

```
String className = char + "Word";
Class c = Class.forName("com.yourWholePackage." + className);
Object obj = c.newInstance(); // get Instance
Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("returnWordArray");
String[] stringy = (String[]) method.invoke(obj);
```

Besides that to simplify your `if-else` you could use `switch-case` and ultimately a different pattern like `Factory` or even `Inheritance`

Comment: Yes. You still need to call returnWordArray, which can be done the hard way (reflection), or, more simply if all the classes implement an interface where the method is defined.

Comment: @MauricePerry Added method aswell

Comment: OK, I would have preferred the other approach, but it should do the job.